# Synonym of 'ladies who lunch'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

So, 'ladies who lunch' is a derogatory term for women with both the means and free time to meet socially for lunch in expensive restaurants. Can anyone think of a more respectful word to use? I don't feel comfortable referring to them as 'women who lunch' as I know it can be pretty offensive.

Comment: 'Moneyed ladies' is probably virtually archaic nowadays.

Comment: *Socialites*, perhaps? *Ladies who lunch* is not **that** derogatory, imo.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170999/what-can-we-call-those-ladies

Comment: 'Ladies of leisure' ?

Comment: Please read: “[single-word-requests tag wiki](/tags/single-word-requests/info)”. In the question, we need to see exactly in what context you want to use the word or phrase – generally we want the sentence you're writing. Specify the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. Detail the research you've already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.). List words or phrases you've already considered but rejected, and explain why. Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for.

Comment: It seems to me that "ladies who lunch" is a splendid three-word description; a sentence with a blank would not help much.  But I hope the OP will post enough to get this reopened.  The possible duplicate is highly opinion-based.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I think referring to them as "women who lunch" is about the least offensive you can get about a group of people - honestly. Be that as it may, what do you think of "ladies who spend a lot of time with each other in expensive restaurants"?

Not sure how that sounds... I am sure there are better and more original alternatives.